# OpenGL 2.0 resizing textures based on object size

Tags: ios, textures, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping

I would like to be able to dynamically repeat textures based on the scale size of a object (cube).

I have tried going through VerticesCube3D structure but get a crash when trying to change the values.  I have my textures setup on repeat but currently it stretches the texture (I need to dynamically change TEX_COORD_MAX)

```
 Vertex VerticesCube3D[] = {
        // Front
        {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
        // Back
        {{1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{-1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
        // Left
        {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
        // Right
        {{1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
        // Top
        {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, 1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
        // Bottom
        {{1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, 0}},
        {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {TEX_COORD_MAX, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, TEX_COORD_MAX}},
        {{-1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}}
    };
```

Comment: You can change texture coordinate values in shader code

Comment: What so pass in a value that * the texture in the shader, got any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to change the texture coordinates in your vertex data (because then you'll have to re-upload it to the hardware). Instead, you want to transform the texture coordinates on the GPU, probably in your vertex shader.

Read about [Projective Texture Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_texture_mapping). This is a pretty common technique, but surprisingly I can't find much in the way of good tutorials about it. [Here's a university programming assignment](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/projects/superquadric/superquadric.pdf) that discusses it a bit.

The gist of it: you define a texture matrix to transform texture coordinate -- this is a transformation just like your model, view, and projection matrices, so on iOS you can create it with `GLKMatrix4` functions just like those. Then provide that matrix to your vertex shader using a uniform variable. In the vertex shader, multiply the input texture coordinate (a vertex attribute) by the texture matrix to transform it before outputting it to a varying for use in the fragment shader.

If you define texture coordinates in your vertex data such that a texture covers an object exactly once, you can then use a texture matrix to scale the texture down. If it's scaled down, and your texture wrap [parameters are set](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) to repeat, your texture will tile across the face of the object.